# How do I select a layer "sitting" under the mouse cursor in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

I'm using GIMP to copy some layer out of a PSD file, But the layers are badly named, So I want to select the correct layer by clicking on the item I wanted to copy.

Which tool should I use, And please provide a screenshot.

Another problem is that sometimes you just can't click anywhere on the image since its layered.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Open Gimp preferences by going to "Edit" menu.

[image]

In "Preferences" dialog box click on "Tool Options" and enable the "set layer or path as active" option.

[image]

Close the "Preferences". Now Click on your desired object and it's layer will be selected automatically. Hare's an example!
[image]

Comment: Hell to tha yeah.

Comment: You also have to Shift + Click with the move tool tested as of GIMP 2.10.18, perhaps this wasn't mentioned because it is obvious for more experience users :-)

Comment: Is it possible to have it selectable with "Selection" tool active and `Mouse Left Button` click like in Photoshop? Currently, it warns with "Cannot substract from an empty selection" if clicked outside of the current layer but on another.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to select a desired layer with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd>. A preview from `GIMP v2.10.30` on Linux [KDE Neon](https://neon.kde.org/) OS:

[image]

---

Related: [Celebrating "Click to Select" in 2.10.10](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Celebrating-Click-to-Select-in-2-10-10?pid=13457#pid13457)